# QML (Qt 5): Overlay button on top left corner of resized image

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have this code (reduced to minimal):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Item {
    Image {
        id: img
        source: "cluster.png"
        width: 150
        height: 150
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
   }

   Button {
        id: butn
        anchors.left: img.left
        anchors.top: img.top
        width: 20
        height: 20
        text: "Push!"
   }
}
```

Which produces an image similar to the following:

[image: Example in qmlscene]

However I would like to put the button at the top left of the *resized* image.

Full image at: http://susepaste.org/34762236

Is this possible with QML?

Comment: Can you please upload cluster.png? It's a bit confusing at the moment.

Comment: @Mitch Good idea, I'll resize (the original is 5000x5000 or so ;) and upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the actual size of the scaled image, in order to so there is the [paintedHeight property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#paintedHeight-prop) and [paintedWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#paintedWidth-prop).

This would result in

```
Item {
    Image {
        id: img
        source: "cluster.png"
        width: 150
        height: 150
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }

    Button {
        id: butn
        anchors.left: img.left
        anchors.top: img.top
        anchors.leftMargin: (img.width - img.paintedWidth)/2
        anchors.topMargin: (img.height - img.paintedHeight)/2
        width: 20
        height: 20
        text: "Push!"
    }
}
```

You can alternatively use `x` or `y` instead of anchors and margins.